# Parsing templates with Python-like if-blocks using pyparsing

Tags: python, regex, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree, pyparsing

I'm trying to parse a simple template language with pyparsing which looks kind of like this:

```py
if <expr>: <statements>
elif <expr>:
    if <expr>:
        <statements>
    else:
        <statements>
<statements>
```

In which statements are either if-blocks with  being valid Python code or any text otherwise. If a string starts with an "if" keyword, that means it's an if-block right away. In fact, lines of text can also contain interpolations of the type `{variable}`, but that's about it.

A full valid example of the this syntax:

```
if a == b: do some {interpolation} stuff
elif a.x > b.y:
    if True:
        some {more} interpolation
        and some more text
    else: foo {bar}
    arbitrary {text} here
lorem {ipsum}
```

To detect Python expressions, I've subclassed `pyparsing.Token` and it sort of seems to work:

```py
import ast
from pyparsing import *

class PythonExpression(Token):
    name = 'PythonExpression'

    def parseImpl(self, s, loc, doActions=True):
        max_loc = s.find('\n') if '\n' in s else len(s)
        best_loc = None
        for n in range(loc + 1, max_loc + 1):
            try:
                tree = ast.parse(s[loc:n])
            except:
                continue
            if isinstance(tree, ast.Module):
                if len(tree.body) is 1:
                    if isinstance(tree.body[0], ast.Expr):
                        best_loc = n
        if best_loc is not None:
            return best_loc, s[loc:best_loc]
        raise ParseException(s, loc, 'invalid Python expression')

expr = 'if foo[1 : "bar:baz"] == 1   :   passqwe'
print (Keyword('if') + PythonExpression()).parseString(expr).asList()
```

results in

```py
['if', 'foo[1 : "bar:baz"] == 1   ']
```

However, I'm a bit lost with the use of `pyparsing.indentedBlock`, cannot seem to make it parse the entire grammar no matter what. My last attempt is this (note that it only contains the `if` statement implementation; there are also optional `elif` and `else` blocks):

```py
ParserElement.setDefaultWhitespaceChars(' \t')

colon = Literal(':').suppress()
if_clause = PythonExpression() + colon
if_statement = Group(Keyword('if') + if_clause)
non_white = Regex(r'\S+')
anything = Combine(non_white + restOfLine)
statement = Forward()
indent_stack = [1]
if_block = Group(if_statement + ((anything) | indentedBlock(statement, indent_stack)))
other = ~Keyword('if') + anything
statement << (if_block | other)
parser = OneOrMore(indentedBlock(statement, indent_stack, False))

data = """\
if foo[1:2]:
  bar
  baz
if foo[3]:
  bar : baz
  if foo[4]: bar
  baz
foo
"""
pprint.pprint(parser.parseString(data).asList())
```

Which starts parsing correctly but then stops:

```py
[[[[['if', 'foo[1:2]'], [['bar'], ['baz']]]]]]
```

I've also tried explicitly adding `+ lineEnd.suppress()` to `anything` but that didn't seem to help. I'm sure I'm doing something stupid here, probably related to newlines, but can't really figure it out.

On a side note, how do I detect interpolation patterns in `anything` in the example above (if the example above was to work), so that `foo {bar} baz` gets parsed to a ['foo', Var('bar'), 'baz']? It's easy to detect `{var}`, but what's the correct expression for plain text then that's not greedy enough to consume everything thrown at it and that doesn't mess up the if/elif/else logic (I tried using `SkipTo` but that became quite cumbersome)?

EDIT: adding the separate grammar for parsing the interpolation with an example:

```py
class Substitution(object):
    def __init__(self, s, l, t):
        self.name = t[0]
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Substitution(%r)' % self.name

ParserElement.setDefaultWhitespaceChars(' \t')
lbrace = Literal('{').suppress()
rbrace = Literal('}').suppress()
name = Word(alphas, alphanums + '_')
substitution = Combine(lbrace + name + rbrace).setParseAction(Substitution)
text = SkipTo(substitution | lineEnd.suppress(), include=True).leaveWhitespace()
parser = OneOrMore(text | substitution)
parser.parseString('hello \n {world} {invalid.sub} \n foo {bar} baz ').asList()
```

outputs

```py
['hello ',
 [' ', Substitution('world')],
 ' {invalid.sub} ',
 [' foo ', Substitution('bar')],
 ' baz ']
```

As you can see, in this case the parser is not being quite correct at grouping lines together (it doesn't allow `text` to follow `substitution` somewhy), but it shows the point. These `Substitution` objects are then to be later processed at runtime.

Comment: Are your interpolation patterns along the lines of compile-time macros, similar to C preprocessor macros, or runtime substitutions. If like preprocessor macros, see the macro example on the pyparsing wiki. If they are runtime, then you will have to include their syntax as part of your parser.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire thanks for your comment; I've added a short example to the original post. I think if I try hard enough I can sort of make it work on its own but not together with the whole indented if blocks grammar.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire I've also added a full working example of the syntax at the top of the post.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire still can't seem to figure it out... my only hope here is your advice :)